# Select2, Select all

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 and I want a "Select All" option, where in all other selected values should be removed and "All" option should be selected. When I choose other available option, "All" option should be removed.

Like:

```
$("#ethnicity").dropdown({
    change : function (curSelVal) {
        if (curSelVal != undefined) {
            if (curSelVal == "") {
                $("#ethnicity > option:selected").attr('selected', false);
                $("#ethnicity option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
            } else {
                $("#ethnicity option:first").attr('selected', false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: its all in the question only.

Comment: @AtinderSingh, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986002/select2-onselect-an-option-will-select-all-other-option/47993325#47993325

Comment: Thnks@beaver, this is great!, but i need a small change. in this answar all the tags are being added to the select box, which is awkward, i mean if i had hundreds of option in my select. They all will be shown in the box. which the users might not like..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538399/jquery-select2-how-to-select-all-options