# trying to use the select all option but its not working

Tags: html, jquery

Trying to follow this:

[Select2 onselect an option will select all other option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986002/select2-onselect-an-option-will-select-all-other-option)

How to edit the function so that I can use it for other drop downs as well without copying the same function again and again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CYCLE RESULTS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <label for="select_platforms_hyper">Hypervisor:</label>
        <select class="parent_filter_select2 pull-right" id="select_platforms_hyper" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="ESXI">ESXI</option>
            <option value="KVM">KVM</option>
        </select>

        <label for="select_platforms_cpu">CPU:</label>
        <select id="select_platforms_cpu">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
        </select>

        <label for="select_platforms_packetsize">Traffic Mix:</label>
        <select id="select_platforms_packetsize">
            <option value="IMIX">IMIX</option>
            <option value="1518">1518</option>
        </select>

        <label for="select_platforms_profiles">Profiles:</label>
        <select multiple id="select_platforms_profiles">
            <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
            <option value="CEF IPv4">CEF IPv4</option>
            <option value="CEF IPv6">CEF IPv6</option>
            <option value="HQOS">HQOS</option>
            <option value="FNF Optimized Mode">FNF Optimized Mode</option>
            <option value="NAT">NAT</option>
            <option value="ZBFW">ZBFW</option>
        </select>


        <label for="select_cycles_sdwan">Cycle:</label>
        <select id="select_cycles_sdwan">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="CCO">CCO</option>
        </select>

        <label id="label_comparison_cycles_sdwan" for="select_comparison_cycles_sdwan">Cycle:</label>
        <select id="select_comparison_cycles_sdwan">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="CCO">CCO</option>
        </select>



<script>
    $("#select_platforms_hyper option").click(function () {
    var val = $(this).attr("value");
    if(val == 'all'){
        $('#select_platforms_hyper option').prop('selected', true);
        $('#select_platforms_hyper option[value="all"]').prop('selected', false);
    }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am unable to see any library addition of `select2` here. I hope you have that. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Now its working, but I need to use it for multiple drop downs

Comment: on the second select box which value will be considered as all like the first one?
or do you want the first one all be selected, then all the other select boxes each value get selected automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code using select2 library.

If you want to have a single function for selecting options, ensure that the name of each all option is the same.

You can check snippet of live preview below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CYCLE RESULTS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
            <label for="select_platforms_hyper">Hypervisor:</label>
            <select class="parent_filter_select2  pull-right" id="select_platforms_hyper" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="ESXI">ESXI</option>
                <option value="KVM">KVM</option>
            </select>
            
            <label for="select_platforms_profiles">Profiles:</label>
        <select multiple id="select_platforms_profiles">
            <option value="all">ALL</option>
            <option value="CEF IPv4">CEF IPv4</option>
            <option value="CEF IPv6">CEF IPv6</option>
            <option value="HQOS">HQOS</option>
            <option value="FNF Optimized Mode">FNF Optimized Mode</option>
            <option value="NAT">NAT</option>
            <option value="ZBFW">ZBFW</option>
        </select>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
<script>
    $('#select_platforms_hyper,#select_platforms_profiles').select2({
              placeholder: "Select an option"
  });
  
  $("#select_platforms_profiles").on('change',function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
        
        if(val == 'all'){
        
          selectAll($(this).attr('id'));
        
        }
  });
  $("#select_platforms_hyper").on('change',function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        
        if(val == 'all'){
        
          selectAll($(this).attr('id'));
        
        }
        });
        
        function selectAll(id){
         $(`#${id} > option`).prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
            $(`#${id} option[value="all"]`).prop('selected', false).trigger('change');
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks. i had to change my question, can you please answer my latest question.

Comment: Let me update my code.

Comment: @AkshayJ just letting you know that I've made some updates to the code. Can you please take a look

Comment: thanks but there is a lot of repetitive code. Can you create a single function which takes arg as the select Id and work